# Redirect to custom url after Shopify app is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I'm getting started with Shopify app development. I'm developing an embedded Shopify app which will be installed to Shopfify stores. After it is installed I want to have separate web pages for Shopify Store Admin and the Shopify Embedded App's Admin, where they can see stats and perform some actions. (I have no idea whether I should keep these pages on the shopify store domain or an external hosted domain, any advice on which one is appropriate for this use case?)

I'm building it in Ruby on Rails using [shopify_app](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) and [shopify_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) gems.
The problem I'm facing is that after app is installed to a Shopify store, by default it is to be  redirected to `/auth/shopify/callback`, which is handled by the `shopify_app` engine and it redirects the app installer(shopify store owner/merchant) to shopify store's domain(see this code [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/6d2bb714a611b15d7366d3f60d53bb428dc23631/app/controllers/shopify_app/callback_controller.rb#L24)).

```rb
module ShopifyApp
  # Performs login after OAuth completes
  class CallbackController < ActionController::Base
    include ShopifyApp::LoginProtection

    def callback
      return respond_with_error if invalid_request?

      store_access_token_and_build_session

      if start_user_token_flow?
        return respond_with_user_token_flow
      end

      perform_post_authenticate_jobs

      respond_successfully
    end

    private

    def respond_successfully
      if jwt_request?
        head(:ok)
      else
        redirect_to(return_address)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the `return_address` definition is

```rb
def return_address
  return base_return_address unless ShopifyApp.configuration.allow_jwt_authentication
  return_address_with_params(shop: current_shopify_domain)
rescue ShopifyDomainNotFound
  base_return_address
end
```

What I want to do is that after the app is installed(oauth permission granted) I want to redirect to a custom URL(preferably some external website, which I'll host for the Shopify Store Admin and the Shopiy App Admin), how is it possible?

> Essentially what I'm attempting is to go to a custom URL instead of the `return_address_with_params(shop: current_shopify_domain)`
> And any pointers on how to handle authentication once we are redirected to that external URL?

I've just started with Shopify App Development and that's why I'm having trouble with understanding these flows. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you choose the "Embedded APP" during the APP setup, then there is no way to handle the APP in both ways, like in the backend Embed iframe and a separate domain APP.

You choose one of these no both.
[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. Is there an alternative to an embedded app which will let me have my pages on an external domain? After the app is installed to a Shopify store?

Comment: yeah, you can use the own login system like your own session and database to handle the same, and link the button inside into backend Iframe APP, once someone clicks over the button you can't open the store data into a new domain with shop data. but I am not 100% how much Shopify support the same and allow into APP

Comment: thanks. Is there something like a non-embedded app offered by Shopify. I have seen apps which do not get embedded after installing to the store. Instead the open in a new tab.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use the Embed feature simply disable it from APP settings and it doesn't redirect you to the backend after installaion.

Comment: that did it. Didn't know about this setting. I need a clarification about this; my understanding is that after the app is installed to store, the browser gets a cookie which is used to authenticate all subsequent calls to the shopify app? Am I correct?

Comment: Sure, once you configure the app into partner account, there is option to load app as embedded into shopify backend. If you want to load or redirect it to 3rd part own domain you need to unselected the option.

Comment: yes, that part is clear to me. What I'm asking is that after I've redirected to that external domain, do I set a cookie in the browser and store the session details there and then use the cookie data to send authenticated requests to my app's backend?

Comment: Yes, you can store data into cookie and session and make API calls to shopify API end points